# Get network connection UID to create a shortlink

Tags: windows, winapi, inno-setup, shortcut, network-connection

I'm using Inno Setup to create an installer for a VPN connection. I need to create a desktop shortcut to a network connection (VPN). When I create manually the shortcut, they point on an UID. How can I get this UID? 
Or, is there any other solution to do that?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I don't need to access to a network share but a network connection (in network manager)

Comment: Added on initial post (thank you Martin Prikryl)

Comment: Maybe you should start with a generic question about retrieving the UID of the network, with tags like [tag:windows] and [tag:winapi]. And only once you find out, ask an Inno Setup-specific question about implementing this.

Comment: You are right. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found an [alternative solution](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/555935) to create a shortcut to a network connection without UID :

- Create a new shortcut
- set location to : C:\Windows\System32\rasphone.exe -d "Connexion VPN"

"Connexion VPN" is simply the name of the connection.